# Product Image background color goes to tranparent in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, product-images

My original png image for product is

[image]

After upload the image the image show on Front end like

[image]

It shows like that why my background colour fade out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please try to upload jpeg/jpg image instead of png image

Comment: Thanks for your response 
will you please tell the issue regarding png image @PushpendraSingh

Comment: check this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14248

Comment: same issue with the jpg image @PushpendraSingh